# Order the locations based on the the polygons in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, geospatial

I have 2 polygons, first polygon inside the second polygon, and i have a locations in the red points some of them in the first polygon and the other in the second, check the below image:

[image]

I need a spatial query in SQL to order the locations based on the polygons, i need the locations in the first polygon comes first then the locations in the second polygon comes last, Also I don't need the locations outside the polygons to appears.

First polygone
path: [ 32.266487,36.034219 , 32.036275,35.806253 , 31.838155,36.080911 , 31.772798,36.391275 , 32.061883,36.410501]

Second polygone
path: [ 32.375757,36.226544 , 32.354697,35.855691 , 32.189814,35.548074 , 31.838155,35.592019 , 31.55773,35.938089 , 31.754116,36.072671 , 31.480465,36.53135 , 31.553049,36.904886 , 31.700385,36.86918 , 31.894138,37.020242 , 32.278098,36.594522]

DB sample for the Locations in red points

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2):

First, some setup:

```sql
use tempdb;
drop table if exists dbo.Neighborhoods;
create table dbo.Neighborhoods (
    NeighborhoodID int not null identity
        constraint PK_Neighborhood primary key clustered,
    Shape geography not null,
    IsHighValue bit not null
);

drop table if exists dbo.Locations;
create table dbo.Locations (
    LocationID int not null identity
        constraint PK_Location primary key clustered,
    Point geography not null
);
declare @a geography = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((
   32.375757 36.226544, 32.354697 35.855691,
   32.189814 35.548074, 31.838155 35.592019,
   31.55773 35.938089, 31.754116 36.072671,
   31.480465 36.53135, 31.553049 36.904886,
   31.700385 36.86918, 31.894138 37.020242,
   32.278098 36.594522, 32.375757 36.226544
))', 4236);
set @a = @a.ReorientObject();

declare @b geography = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((
   32.266487 36.034219, 32.036275 35.806253,
   31.838155 36.080911, 31.772798 36.391275,
   32.061883 36.410501, 32.266487 36.034219
))', 4236);
set @b = @b.ReorientObject();

insert into dbo.Neighborhoods 
    (Shape, IsHighValue)
values
    (@a, 0),
    (@b, 1);

insert into dbo.Locations
    (Point)
values
    (geography::Point(36.6, 31.7, 4236)),
    (geography::Point(36.5, 31.9, 4236)),
    (geography::Point(35.7, 32.2, 4236)),

    (geography::Point(36.2, 31.9, 4236)),
    (geography::Point(36.1, 32.1, 4236));
```

A couple of notes before I move on from that.

1. The format in which you specified your polygons was not immediately consumable by SQL. While the formatting I needed to apply was minor, providing this in the future will make it more likely that people are going to help (i.e. making the barrier to entry low helps *us* help *you*). That said, it might be the case that you're really new to geospatial in SQL and didn't know the right things to Google, so not a big deal.
2. Related to the above, the well-known text (WKT) for the polygons had a couple of problems.

   1. The start and end points need to be the same. That's easy enough to fix by just copy/pasting the start point to the end point
   2. The had what is called a ring orientation problem. For the geography datatype, order in which you specify points matters. In the order specified, the polygon defined a shape that was the entire globe minus a small hole. That's almost certainly not what you wanted, so a call to `ReorientObject()` fixes it. So would have changing the order of the points, but I'm lazy.
3. On the topic of laziness, who has two thumbs and is not inclined to transcribe data from an image into text? Me. Which is why you'll see values like 36.1 in the sample location data instead of the values from your screenshot. The data quality shouldn't matter for this exercise. But again, help us help you if it *does*.

---

Now that we've got the setup out of the way, we're set up to get the data how you'd like it:

```sql
select l.LocationID, IsHighValue
from dbo.Locations as l
outer apply (
    select top(1) n.IsHighValue 
    from dbo.Neighborhoods as n 
    where n.IsHighValue = 1
        and n.Shape.STContains(l.Point) = 1
) as IsInHighValueNeighborhood
order by IsHighValue desc;
```

All this query does is check whether each location is in a high value neighborhood. If it is, we get a value of 1 for IsHighValue. Otherwise we get a NULL (since it didn't find any high value neighborhoods). It's unlikely that you'd need to display that column (it's useful for ordering though); if you do, feel free to do a `coalesce()` or `isnull()` to make it a 0.

To come up with the above, I drew some inference as to what actually mattered (i.e. that there was a notion of one of the neighborhoods being preferred because it had higher real estate prices). If you literally want a more arbitrary notion of neighborhood ordering, you can change the `n.IsHighValue = 1` predicate in the outer apply to something like `n.NeighborhoodID = 2`. Or anything you want really.

Answer (score 0):

Ben has great explanation, but I would use a simpler (and more generic) query. First, use simple JOIN, and second use `value` instead of `IsHighValue` so you can have multiple polygon priorities.

```
select l.LocationID, max(value) as value
from dbo.Locations as l 
join dbo.Neighborhoods as n
  on n.Shape.STIntersects(l.Point)
group by l.LocationID
order by value desc;
```

this simply

1. joins all locations with polygons, dropping all points that are not inside at least one polygon,
2. groups by location selecting highest polygon value when a point is within multiple polygons.